# NEST Elastic query works for a few hours and then stops

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I have a very strange situation with Elasticsearch 5.4 and NEST 5.4.0.  I have written a simple C# console app that queries Elastic once per minute and returns hits/documents and stores them in a Postgres database for further processing.  It works very well for a few hours and then begins to return queries with valid .DebugInformation with zero documents yet I can copy and run the same query in Kibana Dev Tools and get results. When I stop the console app and restart it then it successfully queries and returns hits and all is well.  Below are code samples and log entries.  I am trying to figure out why it stops working after awhile.  I am using .NET Core C# Console app with NEST.

I am not sure if the .DebugInformation is returning any info about the ES health at that moment to see if there are issues with the ES cluster at that moment like 429s.  I have looked at the elasticsearch.log and that only shows inserts.  I am not sure if there is a place to find query problems.

Has anyone had issues of NEST working fine and then stopping?

Here is a query log with two runs.  The first runs fine and returns 9 rows (I removed all but one in the sample due to sensitive data) and then it runs again but returns zero hits.  All queries after that have zero hits in them until I restart the C# code again. Same start and end date inputs and I get the real data in Elastic....

```
2017-09-12 16:41:59.799 -05:00 [Information] Dates: Start 9/12/2017 4:41:00 PM End 9/12/2017 4:42:00 PM
2017-09-12 16:41:59.800 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._queryErrors: 9/12/2017 4:41:00 PM End 9/12/2017 4:42:00 PM
2017-09-12 16:41:59.811 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: elasticQuery {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter":
                            [ {
                                "range":
                                { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-09-12T21:41:00Z",
                                                    "lte": "2017-09-12T21:42:00Z" }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "exists" : { "field" : "error_data" }
                              }
                            ]
                        } }
2017-09-12 16:41:59.811 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: searchResponse 9 : Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /filebeat-%2A/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://servername:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0112120
# Request:
{"from":0,"query":{
                    "bool": {
                        "filter":
                            [ {
                                "range":
                                { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-09-12T21:41:00Z",
                                                    "lte": "2017-09-12T21:42:00Z" }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "exists" : { "field" : "error_data" }
                              }
                            ]
                        } }
# Response:
{"took":7,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":215,"successful":215,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":9,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[{"_index":"filebeat-2017.09.12","_type":"log","_id":"AV54Cdl2yay890uCUru4","_score":0.0,"_source":{"offset":237474,"target_url":"...url...","input_type":"log","source":"....source....","type":"log","tags":["xxx-001","beats_input_codec_plain_applied","@timestamp":"2017-09-12T21:41:02.000Z","@version":"1","beat":{"hostname":"xxx-001","name":"xxx-001","version":"5.4.3"},"host":"xxx-001","timestamp":"09/12/2017 16:41:02","error_data":"EXCEPTION, see detail log"}]}

2017-09-12 16:41:59.811 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._queryErrors: (result) System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XX.Alerts.Core.Models.FilebeatModel]
2017-09-12 16:41:59.811 -05:00 [Information] ErrorCount: 9

2017-09-12 16:42:00.222 -05:00 [Information] Dates: Start 9/12/2017 4:42:00 PM End 9/12/2017 4:43:00 PM
2017-09-12 16:42:00.222 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._queryErrors: 9/12/2017 4:42:00 PM End 9/12/2017 4:43:00 PM
2017-09-12 16:42:00.229 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: elasticQuery {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter":
                            [ {
                                "range":
                                { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-09-12T21:42:00Z",
                                                    "lte": "2017-09-12T21:43:00Z" }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "exists" : { "field" : "error_data" }
                              }
                            ]
                        } }
2017-09-12 16:42:00.229 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: searchResponse 0 : Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /filebeat-%2A/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://servername:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0066742
# Request:
{"from":0,"query":{
                    "bool": {
                        "filter":
                            [ {
                                "range":
                                { "@timestamp": { "gte": "2017-09-12T21:42:00Z",
                                                    "lte": "2017-09-12T21:43:00Z" }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "exists" : { "field" : "error_data" }
                              }
                            ]
                        } }
# Response:
{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":215,"successful":215,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

2017-09-12 16:42:00.229 -05:00 [Debug] AlertService._queryErrors: (result) System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Q2.Alerts.Core.Models.FilebeatModel]
2017-09-12 16:42:00.229 -05:00 [Information] ErrorCount: 0
```

Here is my NEST query

```
    public IEnumerable<FilebeatModel> _elasticQueryLogErrors(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //var startDateString = startDate.Kind;
        //var endDateString = endDate.Kind;

        var searchQuery = @"{
                ""bool"": {
                    ""filter"":
                        [ {
                            ""range"":
                            { ""@timestamp"": { ""gte"": """ + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}", startDate.ToUniversalTime()) +
                    @""",
                                                ""lte"": """ + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}", endDate.ToUniversalTime()) + @""" }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            ""exists"" : { ""field"" : ""error_data"" }
                          }
                        ]
                    } }";

        var searchResponse = _es.Search<FilebeatModel>(s => s
            .AllTypes()
            .From(0)
            .Query(query => query.Raw(searchQuery)));

        _logger.LogDebug("AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: elasticQuery " + searchQuery);

        _logger.LogDebug("AlertService._elasticQueryLogErrors: searchResponse " + searchResponse.Hits.Count + " : " + searchResponse.DebugInformation);

        foreach (var searchResponseHit in searchResponse.Hits)
        {
            searchResponseHit.Source.Id = searchResponseHit.Id;
        }

        return searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
    }
```

Here is my constructor of the class that is running the above code in a loop.  The loops may run for hours or days.  This may be the area of my issue is how the connection is constructed for a long period of time.  When I close and reopen the app running the queries over the period missed they run just fine.

```
    public AlertService(IOptions<ElasticConfig> elasticConfig, AlertsDbContext context, ILogger<AlertService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.LogDebug(" *** Entering AlertService");
        string elasticConnectionString = elasticConfig.Value.ConnectionString;
        string defaultIndex = elasticConfig.Value.IndexName;

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                new Uri(elasticConnectionString))
            .ConnectionLimit(-1)
            .DisableDirectStreaming()
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

        _es = new ElasticClient(settings);
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: One interesting piece of info is that at 01:11 you query the last minute, i.e. from 01:10 to 01:11. Yet at 01:14 you query the next minute, i.e. 01:14 to 01:15, which cannot yet return any info since it's in the future at that very moment. So the problem might be in how you compute those dates you use in the `range` query.

Comment: It is actually not in the future....I thread sleep the process for a minute and then query again so the chunk of my log is probably misleading. I grabbed 3 min later. Will add 1:12 instead

Comment: Well, if you look at the log timestamps and the related range query, it's pretty clear that they don't align properly. Feel free to update the logs to whatever you think will better reflect the reality and we can have another look at it.

Comment: Thanks Val.  I updated the logs.  One thing I have noticed is that the runs are very close together almost overlapping.  Wondering if NESTs internals are fried after two queries try to run at the same time.  When i restart the code with the start and end date params the same as what pulled zero hits I get them all just fine.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is a possibly a race condition bug in NEST. When two queries are run within a second of each other NEST will return a valid query response but not return results. If anyone has advice on capturing elastic query traffic to confirm what is inbound for the NEST request that would help. I have seen notes about using Packetbeat as a capture mechanism but your wisdom is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for uploading new logs. But again this log show s exactly the same issue as before. You're running two queries, one at 16:41:59 and another the next second at 16:42:00. The first one queries data between 16:41 and 16:42, which is ok because at that time you have 59 seconds of data, but the second one queries data between 16:42:00 and 16:43:00, which is NOT ok, because that range is in the future at that time. I don't see how you expect the second query to return anything. In order to return something, the second query should run at 16:43:00

Comment: @dodegaard feel free to open an issue to discuss if you think there's a race condition: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues

Comment: Thanks Val and Russ Cam for your comments.  I have answered it as Val pointed out in the timing of my variables and the call to Elastic.  NEST is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is a race condition created by myself as the internal timer creeps up on the call to Elastic as Val pointed out in the comments. It is not a bug in NEST but simply my code and its timing.  I have aligned the call using System.Threading.Timer into a single callback per elapse and it works properly.  Thanks to Val for his assistance